# set x Axis range in google chart

Tags: google-visualization

I try to create bar chart using google chart example

```
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');

    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');

    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 5],
      ['Onions', 4],
      ['Olives', 3]
      ['Zucchini', 2],
      ['Pepperoni', 1]
    ]);
```

Chart is created successfully but on X-Axis it shows value from 0 to 6.
When i pass all values as 0 it shows X-Axis from -1 to +1.

Is it possible to set X-Axis to always start from 0% to 100%.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can force the x-axis of a BarChart to always show a certain range by setting the `hAxis.viewWindow.min` and `hAxis.viewWindow.max` options:

```
hAxis: {
    viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    },
    ticks: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100] // display labels every 25
}
```

Comment: I tested it in chrome and firefox and on max:100 it shows range upto 80 and when i set it to max:100.1 it shows range upto 100.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the axis labels, since the actual range of the axis should be 0-100 in the example case.  If you want to change the labels chosen by the API by default, you can override them with the `hAxis.ticks` option; I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Is there a way to create viewWindow with date range? I tried `viewWindow: { min: new Date(2016,1,1),  max: new Date(2016,1,8) }` but the resulting range on the x-axis is not 1-8 of jan .. it seems to be off..

Comment: Oh. my bad works as it should. January month has index 0 . So should be `viewWindow: { min: new Date(2016,0,1), max: new Date(2016,0,8) }`  to have as range 1st-jan to 8th-jan. Also _be_sure_ NOT to start your month or days with leading zero eg. `012` because JS will interpret it as octal constant.

Answer (score 4):

Set the `tick` values:

```
vAxis: { 
         ticks: [{v:0, f:'0%'},{v:10, f:'10%'},{v:20, f:'20%'},{v:30, f:'30%'}]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

u can set x axis by modifing count value as we are using DataTable()

var databmi = new google.visualization.DataTable();

```
 data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
      data.addColumn('number', 'GDP');
      data.addRows([
        ['US', 16768100],
        ['China', 9181204],
        ['Japan', 4898532],
        ['Germany', 3730261],
        ['France', 2678455]
      ]);

     var options = {
       title: 'GDP of selected countries, in US $millions',
       width: 500,
       height: 300,
       legend: 'none',
       bar: {groupWidth: '95%'},
       vAxis: { 
             title :'your choice',
             gridlines: { count: 4 } 
              },
        hAxis: {
               title :'your choice',
                gridlines: {count: 4}
              }
     };
```