# Changing x axis ticks in Material google bar charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to build a usage bar chart using https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#top-x.
I was wondering how can I maximize the range of the X-axis tick marks? I've tried doing that in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gbta075L/ using the suggestion from another post - [set x Axis range in google chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341285/set-x-axis-range-in-google-chart) but that did not work. This is what I added to the existing fiddle:

```
hAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
              max: 200
        },
        ticks: [0,50,100]
}
```

but that does not seem work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I honestly dont know how to construct the `ticks` and `viewWindow` equivalences when using googles material bar charts. It is not so well documented and still in beta.

However, a nice trick is to use `google.charts.Bar.convertOptions()` which translates google visualization options into material chart options :

```
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

results in this

[image]

Which I assume is what you want.
forked fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/65bwmknu/**

Comment: Its worth noting that only the hAxis.viewWindow.max is being applied, not hAxis.ticks (At least at the time of this comment https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143 )