# How to set the "X" and "Y" range

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bubble-chart

I would like to set the min and max for the chart.

Currently, the range of the x and y axis are dependent on the data that is provided to the chart. Although, I would like to have that fixed.

See the chart below

[image]

I would like the min and max of the chart to be at "5"

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341285/set-x-axis-range-in-google-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart#configuration-options), you can use the following...

```
    hAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5
      },
      ticks: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    },
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5
      },
      ticks: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['X', 'Y'],
        [1, 1]
      ]),
      {
        hAxis: {
          viewWindow: {
            min: 0,
            max: 5
          },
          ticks: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        },
        vAxis: {
          viewWindow: {
            min: 0,
            max: 5
          },
          ticks: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }
      }
    );
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Tried that, although it still uses the data values and trims the chart to its range.

Comment: Your right, it works! I guess I was doing something wrong, thanks!